# every day xpath are changing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, netweaver

I'm doing automation for SAP.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__box23-arrow\"]")).click();dropdown
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__item1283-__box23-2\"]")).click();
```

Every time my xpath changes `//*[@id=\"__box23-arrow\ example //*[@id=\"__box24-arrow\`.

Can you please give any other solution?

Comment: Add Relevant HTML of your target Element

Comment: HTML code is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your xpath will always be changing, to get your Selenium code to work atleast there should be some pattern in how it changes, for example it may be dependent on current date. Then you can code accordingly to generate your xpath dynamically every time you run your script. If there is no such pattern and no static content to be able to use `contains` in xpath, you should check out other tools like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). It uses image recognition to identify your element. This again assumes that the visible aspect of your element remains same.

There is also a wave of new testing products powered by AI like [Testim](https://www.testim.io/) which are "self healing", meaning they will adapt to changes in the source code. I haven't used them but they are probably what you want.

Comment: Hi @shivam i m using Sikuli with selenium, my project are not runing in comand prompt and jenkins can you please suggest me what i can do for this. error is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sikuli/script/Screen .

Comment: @PoojaPathange raise another question with proper details. You can then send me the link of the question to my linkedin profile perhaps (link in my bio). Thanks

Comment: I'm blocked to ask new questions, don't know why I need help to run my Selenium + sikuli projects in Command prompt and jenkins. Currently project running in ecplise.

Comment: @PoojaPathange Please share the full details to my linkedin profile or skype id: Shivam.kiwiqa

Answer (score 0):

If you know the beginning of your id which is static throughout in that case you can go for

```
"//*[@id*='__box']"
```

This will give you element(s) whose id starts with '__box'

Hope this helps!

Comment: `xpath` doesn't have `*=`, its used in `cssSelector`.

Comment: @Guy Sorry forgot to mention that part. Thanks..
PoojaPathange You'll have to use cssSelector instead of xpath

Comment: @KarthikeyanR css selector paths are not executing

Comment: <span tabindex="-1" id="__box24-arrow" role="button" aria-labelledby="__text60" class="sapMComboBoxArrow sapMComboBoxBaseArrow sapMComboBoxTextFieldArrow"><span id="__text60" data-sap-ui="__text60" class="sapUiInvisibleText" aria-hidden="true">Arrow Down</span></span>

Comment: above is sap id this id="__box24-arrow" will always change .Any other posible way to write xpath –

Comment: You have been given class name as well. you can try and use that
`span[class='sapMComboBoxArrow sapMComboBoxBaseArrow sapMComboBoxTextFieldArrow']`

Comment: By class name you can find xpath as :
"//span[@class='sapMComboBoxArrow sapMComboBoxBaseArrow sapMComboBoxTextFieldArrow']"

OR find out what is constant in id ( __box24-arrow) and then you can use contains method
for example: 
//*[contains(@id,'__box24')]
//*[contains(@id,'arrow')]

Comment: no sorry none of the above codes are working

Answer (score 0):

You can write dynamic xpath using contains keyword as well.

Please refer example below -

```
//a[contains(@id, 'ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell')
```

Comment: <span tabindex="-1" id="__box24-arrow" role="button" aria-labelledby="__text60" class="sapMComboBoxArrow sapMComboBoxBaseArrow sapMComboBoxTextFieldArrow"><span id="__text60" data-sap-ui="__text60" class="sapUiInvisibleText" aria-hidden="true">Arrow Down</span></span>

Comment: above is sap id this  id="__box24-arrow" will always change .Any other posible way to write xpath

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared with us , You can try with this **xpath** :

```
//span[@role='button' and contains(@class,'sapMComboBoxArrow sapMComboBoxBaseArrow sapMComboBoxTextFieldArrow')]
```